# Export Sametime buddylist from vpuserinfo.nsf use lotusscript

Tags: lotus-domino, lotusscript, lotus, sametime

I know we can get access to custom data of vpuserinfo.nsf using: `byteArray = notesDocument.GetItemValueCustomDataBytes( itemName$ , dataTypeNam$)`

But i don't know the datatypename of "8193". Can somebody tell me what datatype name the field "8193" is?

Answer (score 0):

The datatypname is "ubqOpaque"

Example:
doc.GetItemValueCustomDataBytes("8193", "ubqOpaque")

Be aware, that writing the datstream is more involved than just change the values. There are a few bytes at the beginning of the bytearray etc. that indicate how big the field is and things.  So not very straight forward and not documented.